# What is the concurrent.futures-equivalent of multiprocessing.Lock?

Tags: python, future, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

For consistency, I'm trying to port some older code based on `multiprocessing` to `concurrent.futures` (using `ProcessPoolExecutor`). In my old code, I'm using the [Lock](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) class to synchronize writing to stdout. I can't seem to find a similar class in `concurrent.futures`. Is there one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

concurrent.futures is implemented on top of multiprocessing that is why it does not provide such an interface itself. You can test this by passing a lock to as a job argument.

Comment: So should I simply use `multiprocessing.Lock` in the new code?

Comment: Accepting this, and for future reference: I did just use `multiprocessing.Lock` which worked perfectly.